# How to make sidebar fixed in adminlte template mvc?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-5, adminlte

I've got a web application in MVC5 and I'm using an **AdminLTE** template for design. My problem is that sidebar is not static in header.

The `navbar` is using `navbar navbar-fixed-top` class, but the sidebar is not aligned properly. What class should be used to fix this?

Here is a screenshot of the problem

[image]

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `fixed` class to the `body` to make sidebar fixed and aligned with the navbar.